# Copying from location a to location b in source wchar* to destination wchar* from location c, without null terminating

Tags: c, c++11, copy, memcpy, wchar

Is there any C/C++11 function like

```
whcar_t* source,destiantion;
int location;

copy(source,destination,location,partOfSource);
```

That copies partOfSource wchar-s from source to destination, starting from location in destination and location 0 in source, without terminating destination string with L'\0' ?

Thanks!

Comment: C or C++? C++ uses `std::wstring` while C uses `wchar_t *`.

Comment: The C++ standard library have many [algorithmic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), including a few to [copy data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) between containers.

Comment: Oh and there's no such thing as "C/C++". Either you program in C, or you program in C++. They are two very different languages.

Comment: like `wstrncpy(destination+location,source,partOfSource)` or so?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, but maybe you are looking for [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).

Comment: What's the point of __not__ terminating the destination string with `L'\0'` ? How is the destination string used once the copy has taken place? I'm smelling an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: I use wchar_t* so C.
Well I am building a c to JSON converter, so I don't need every copy to put L'\0' in the end of it. I want to just append characters and than when I have full JSON string I will add L'\0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function for this in the C++ standard library. This works for any pointed type (`char`, `wchar_t`, `int`, `whatever`) and treats all values equally (no special treatment for a terminating value). This also works for all types of forward iterators, not just pointers.

```
std::copy(source, std::next(source, partOfSource), std::next(destination, location));
```

Comment: What about edge cases? Does it copy destination+location location, or up until that ?
Thanks, anyway, this is my answer!

Comment: @Vess It copies into destination starting from `destination + location`.